# Stream live audio to mobile devices

Tags: mobile, real-time, html5-audio, audio-streaming, webrtc

I would like to gather some thoughts on real-time audio streaming.
I want to stream audio from a live source (like a mic) to mobile devices. I thought about doing it via browser on the client side to keep it simple. A major concern of mine is the delay I might face. I would like to stream to multiple devices with little to none delay, so the phones would be almost synchronous when playing. I was thinking of using WebRTC, but I'm not too sure about that. Any experience or thoughts someone would like to share on this topic?

Comment: Would you like to build native mobile apps like iOS/Android?

Comment: I could, but I don't believe that it would make it significantly easier. I guess it also may be good to do the work on the server and only use the phones browsers, so I could probably support some cheaper android phones, too. I also don't need any extra functions other than streaming, so I would like to try it with html5 first instead of doing it native.

Comment: With mobile browsers it will be much easier to build. Yes, you can use WebRTC, but WebRTC doesn't support multiple chats, you have build it by yourself

Comment: So WebRTC is 1-1 only? But would it be possible to open several connections on one server to n phones? It would be different streams of course, it may be difficult to keep them synchronous then, right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it, It will be enough synchronous.

Comment: Sounds good, thank you. I guess I will give that a try. But other opinions or thoughts are still very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Because of your latency requirement, WebRTC is essentially the only good option for you.

Yes, WebRTC **does** support multiple users at the same time.

Look into OpenTok for iOS.